# Setting range boundaries in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database with a column called "level", which stores integers that increment from 1 upwards.

I'd like to run a select statement (which will also have various other conditions) to retrieve those rows that are the first, and last, of each "level", i.e. the boundaries of each level.  But I have tens of millions of records, so would like to do this in the most efficient way possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how would you determine which rows at each level are the 'first' and 'last'?

Comment: This question has been asked many times in SO -- you should search first.  In general, you'll need to specify how to determine order (i.e. first and last), and what to do with duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll call the variable that determines first and last `something`. I suppose it is a timestamp, but you didn't tell us.

If you need one column from the row, then

```
 SELECT level, MAX(something) as maxie, MIN(something) as minnie
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY level;
```

If you want the whole row, make sure to use a database with windowing functions

```
 SELECT DISTINCT first_value(mytable) over www, last_value(mytable) over www 
 FROM mytable
 WINDOW www as (partition by level order by level, something 
    RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND unbounded following);
```

If these are too slow, there *might* be some gimmicks based on clever indexing of `level` and `something`. I'm still learning windowing, which is new to Postgres 9 but has been in Oracle for years. (It isn't in MySQL; there you probably need to get PKs of the extrema and do a join.)